# Is there a way to get the language from Medium posts?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I need to review numerous articles every day, however, I'm only interested in articles in a specific language (Portuguese, pt-br, in this case).

I even read [Medium's API](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs) and didn't find language information, but I'm not a technical reference lol

I would like to:

1. Know if there is any way to get the language parameters of an article from Medium (Medium.com) to be able to return only articles in Portuguese
2. If not possible, recommendations on how I could collect published articles, and filter them by language using another technique or technology (e.g.: artificial intelligence)

Comment: Its possible to identify the language of any text using AWS Comprehend, specifically "DetectDominantLanguage". You can use the AWS SDK in your project for free, but it will require some considerable setuo to use this to solve your problem, because a) you would have to identify the language for EVERY article in order to pick out the Portuguese ones and b) you'd need software whihc connects to AWS services. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_DetectDominantLanguage.html

Comment: @Leon thank you so much for your answer!

So, the best (but uncertain) case scenario would be if Medium's add language as a property that could get, right?

Your suggestion is awesome and now I realize that would be a complex thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Medium currently does not support a way to filter stories by language.
But you can  change the app language. If your app doesn't load in your language, you can easily change that in your phone settings.
you can follow this link for further details
[about language availability on medium](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035241933-About-language-availability-on-Medium)